# Azure Custom Decision Service API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Custom Decision Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-decision-service/custom-decision-service-overview) and have a few API questions.

1. From the documentation, I'm seeing that there is a Reward API for user clicking on the first recommended article. But is there other click events? Is the service also "learn" when user click on an article that isn't in the recommended list?
2. I couldn’t find where we send user info, how does Custom Decision Service helps with article “personalization”? Is it based on a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At the moment,  we're only learning from a click on the top slot or first recommended article. We are considering enhancing the Decision Service to support learning from clicks on multiple slots but this is not yet in the service.
2. We automatically generate user features, today we use geo location and device type. We do use cookies but we're not learning from those yet.

Comment: Has this limitation of only being able to reward/learn from the first item in the recommendations been fixed since the time this comment was written last year?